# JS - get #id instead of.val()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

is there any way to get id instead of value where

> $('#' + $(this).val()).show();

```
$(function() {
  $('#inputtype').change(function(){
    $('.fastallow').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="inputtype" class="form-control" name="typeof"> 
     <option value="FALSE" selected>Methods</option> 
    <?php foreach ($mb as $namee): ?> <option id="<?= $namee->u_ft; ?>" value="<?= $namee->username; ?>"><?= $namee->vn; ?></option> 
    <?php endforeach ;?> 
</select>
```

and

```
<div class="form-row fastallow" id="1" style="display:none;">
.
.
.
</div>
```

I want to display div only where option id = 1

Comment: Please show relevant html so we know what you are trying to accomplish along with a proper written explanation

Comment: Also take a few minutes to read [mcve]

Comment: <select id="inputtype" class="form-control" name="typeof">
      
        <option value="FALSE" selected>Methods</option>
                <?php foreach ($mb as $namee): ?>
        <option id="<?= $namee->u_ft; ?>" value="<?= $namee->username; ?>"><?= $namee->vn; ?></option>
                 <?php endforeach ;?>

      </select>

Comment: [Edit] details please instead of posting in the comments where formatting multiline code is impossible making it really hard to read.

Comment: oh sorry I've already add it

Comment: Please only show generated html not server side code. And explain what it is you are trying to do in words. So far it is completely unclear what it is you want to show and how it relates to the <select>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition

Use a data-attribute on the `<option>` instead and use `:selected` selector to target selected `<option>` in order to access that attribute

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inputtype').change(function(){
    // "this" is the <select>
    $('.fastallow').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).find(':selected').data('id')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.fastallow{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="inputtype" class="form-control" name="typeof">
   <option></option>
   <option data-id="1" value="someVal">One</option>
   <option data-id="2"  value="anotherVal">Two</option>
</select>
<div id="1" class="fastallow">Content One</div>
<div id="2" class="fastallow">Content Two</div>
```

Comment: if it helps feel free to accept it. Will get faster answers in future and less clarification questions by being a bit more prepared with code and your problem explanations before posting next question. Not being critical of you, just part of learning curve using the site